# Connection Issue: socketIO with microservices using kubernetes

Tags: typescript, kubernetes, socket.io, next.js, microservices

Basically, I have microservices architecture where i have different services such as client, orders, payments, etc.. and this services have their own express server.

So, I want to implement realtime feedback using socketio. Currently, I'm using kubernetes and nginx for running this services in the containers using docker and minikube.

So, how to connect client service with others servers like orders, payments for listening to events from different services.

In order service I have created server as follows:

```js
// * imports for socketIO
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import socketIO from 'socket.io';

// * declare io globally
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
      interface Global {
          io: socketIO.Server 
      }
  }
}

// * create express app
const app = express();

// * create a globally define socket
const server = http.createServer(app);
global.io = new socketIO.Server(server);

// * On connection with server
global.io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log(`New ${socket.client} client connected`);

  socket.emit('conn', 'connected');

  // * If client disconnects
  socket.on('disconnect', reason => {
    console.log(reason);
  })
});
```

So, Need help to connect this services and be able to use socketIO

And on client side I'm using next.js and **I'm not able to connect with the backend.**
Note: As I'm using nginx service with kubernetes and the config file is as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: auth-srv
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/orders/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: orders-srv
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/payments/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: payments-srv
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-srv
              servicePort: 3000
```

And the frontend client service code for connecting is as below:

```js
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { io } from "socket.io-client";

function useSocket(url) {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const socketIo = io(url)

    setSocket(socketIo)

    function cleanup() {
      socketIo.disconnect()
    }
    return cleanup

    // should only run once and not on every re-render,
    // so pass an empty array
  }, [])

  return socket
}

const Home = ({ events, reqErr }) => {
  // In order to connect to orders service
  const socket = useSocket('/api/orders');

  // * Handle Error
  if (events === undefined || reqErr) {
    return (
      <div className="handle-error">
        <center>
          <h1 style={{color: 'red', margin: '20rem auto'}}> Can't Load page <br /> Error {reqErr.message}</h1>
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.on('conn', data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
    }
  }, [socket]);
  

  // * Rendering the page
  return (
    <div>
      Rendered
    </div>
  )
}


Home.getInitialProps = async (context, client, currentUser) => {
// Sending request to order service
};

export default Home;
```

Need advice or approach to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticky sessions are needed when using socket io in kubernetes. Else a service in kubernetes cluster will send request to different pods on each request from client machine which leads to issues at client end. You can look into below doc for more info.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/

Comment: Thanks bro will try this